# Can you cancel out the derivative function - very new to calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

I'm incredibly new to calculus (I'm a high school freshman and I'm doing a summer camp that involves calculus when I've only just completed geometry). While I do enjoy the rigor of the course, it is daunting to have to self study when you barely know where to look and can barely understand math tutorials because the information and problems presented to me is so far from my normal - So I understand if my question might seem stupid or silly  but I truly am so lost.

My question is - can you cancel out the derivative function - for example if you have have been given that the position of a particle is $x = 20t - 5t^3$ where $x$ is in meters and $t$ is in seconds and you are asked to find where the velocity is equal to zero, you first have to find what $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is (I assume). So then you get $\frac{\mathrm{d}(20t - 5t^3)}{\mathrm{d}t}$. I looked at the answer for guidance and it says the answer for that equation is $20t - 15t$ which I don't understand unless you can cancel out the differential functions and then the $t$'s. I am finding a lot of flaws with my logic but if someone could please give me a step by step answer to this without skipping my steps (because I probably could not figure out how to go from one to the other), that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the "[power rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation#The_polynomial_or_elementary_power_rule)" for differentiation? as well as the "[sum rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation#Differentiation_is_linear)"?  Or do you (only) know the definition of the derivative?

Comment: $x= 20t - 5t^3 \implies \frac{dx} {dt} = 20 - 15t^2$. Please look up the rules of differentiation of polynomial functions (often one of the first things taught in basic calculus).

Comment: The word is spelled "derivative". ("Derisive" is another word, not about mathematics.)

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can typeset the mathematics properly.

Comment: @EricTowers I know how to solve for d(x) (I just understood my mistake for why 20t - 15t is incorrect but should instead by 20 - 15t, but I'm confused about the lower half? Why do we ignore it I thought that we were supposed to divide by the derivative  of whatever t was.

Comment: Look up differentiation from 1st principles. Nothing was ignored but limits were taken.

Comment: $d(x)$ is not a thing that you solve for.  It is not even immediately obvious how to make sense of that collection of symbols---at your level, you should probably regard $d/dt$ and $dx/dt$ as single symbols, and not as "fractions" or decomposable collections of other symbols.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but if you're new to calculus and want a solid conceptual understanding, 3Blue1Brown's "Essence of Calculus" is a fantastic video series that distills all of the important conceptual points of a basic single variable calculus course into a 10 or so video long series. For content regarding the nitty gritty details about how to actually solve problems, Khan Academy is a fantastic resource.

Answer (score 1):

Using only the definition of the derivative...

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}f(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(t+\Delta t) - f(t)}{(t+\Delta t) - t}
\end{align*}
(This should very much look like a "slope of a line" computation.  We have the change in the output of the function divided by the change in the input to the function, $\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta t}$.  We are taking the limit as the "nudge" in the input shrinks to zero, since we just want to know the rate of change of the output to change of the input, which is indicated in the derivative notation by the change from "$\Delta$"s to "$\mathrm{d}$"s.)
\begin{align*}
&= \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(20(t+\Delta t) - 5(t+\Delta t)^3) - (20t - 5t^3)}{\Delta t}  \\
&= \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{20t  +20\Delta t - 5t^3 - 15 t^2 \Delta t - 15 t (\Delta t)^2 - 5(\Delta t)^3 - 20t + 5t^3}{\Delta t}  \\
&= \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{20\Delta t - 15 t^2 \Delta t - 15 t (\Delta t)^2 - 5(\Delta t)^3 }{\Delta t}  \\
&= \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \left( 20 - 15 t^2 - 15 t \Delta t - 5(\Delta t)^2 \right)  \\
&= 20 - 15 t^2 - 15 t (0)- 5(0)^2  \\
&= 20 - 15 t^2  \text{.}
\end{align*}
(Here we discharge the limit using the continuity of polynomials.  Here, we have a polynomial in $\Delta t$.  Recall that a function is continuous if (and only if) for all inputs, its value agrees with its limits approaching those inputs.  So we evaluate the limit of the continuous function by evaluating the function at the limit.)

Answer (score 0):

If $ x(t) = 20 t - 5t^3$, then $x'(t) = 20 - 15t^2$.

The derivative rule for polynomials is
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt} at^b = (a \times b) t^{b-1}.
$$

Comment: Importantly $b \neq -1$

Comment: @Karl $D (1/t) = -1/t^2$. Do you mean "Importantly, $b \neq 0$" or something about the domain? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ignore me. I typed this early in the morning and was integrating. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In Leibniz derivative notation, which can be written as: $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(20t - 5t^3\right),$$the $d$ and $dt$ are not variables; they simply show what order derivative is with respect to what variable.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(20t - 5t^3\right)\ne 20t-15t=5t.$$

To find the derivative, you need to apply the power rule to the second term:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(20t - 5t^3\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(20t\right) - \frac{d}{dt}\left(5t^3\right)=20-15t^2$$.